# Using linux environment variables in cloudformation cfn-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, docker-swarm

In my cloudformation template in the command section the $SWARM_TOKEN variable is not picked up as a string value by the aws cli command. The idea is to store the token in the parameter store for later use.

code i use in the configset:

```
AWS::CloudFormation::Init:....
      
get_and_store_swarm_token:
                  commands:
                    get_and_store_token:
                      command: !Sub 
                        SWARM_TOKEN=$(sudo docker swarm join-token -q worker)
                        aws ssm put-parameter --name "SwarmToken" --type "SecureString" --value $SWARM_TOKEN --overwrite --region ${AWS::Region}
```

When i ssh into the EC2 linux host i can execute the commands and they work.
So i think that the cfn-init command somehow starts a session where the $SWARM_TOKEN variable is not seen as a string. Any thought on how to make the cli command work so that the $SWARM_TOKEN variable is recognized?

Comment: Thanks Marcin, It works!

Comment: with echo 'export SWARM_TOKEN="'$SWARM_TOKEN'"'>> ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So i think that the cfn-init command somehow starts a session where the $SWARM_TOKEN variable is not seen as a string.

You are correct. You would have to update `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` using your `cfn-init` to `export` your `SWARM_TOKEN` for regular users.